# Categorizing pandas dataframe series values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, grouping

I am new to pandas and trying to automatically create categories and group the values.

My dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Slug': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
                   'Position': ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '0', '1', '2', '3', '0', '1', '2'],
                   'Brand': ['Mazda', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Fiat', 'Dodge', 'Mazda', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Fiat', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Fiat'],
                   'Sessions': ['70', '', '', '', '', '60', '', '', '', '50', '', ''],
                   'Transactions': ['1', '', '', '', '', '2', '', '', '', '3', '', ''],
                   'Ecommerce': ['1', '', '', '', '', '3', '', '', '', '4', '', ''],
                   'CTR': ['10', '', '', '', '', '15', '', '', '', '5', '', ''],
                   'All': ['11', '', '', '', '', '1', '', '', '', '4', '', '']})
```

I am trying to answer a question: which layout of brands has the best conversion. Position column declares the way brands are writtien down on the site:

Example:

```
0 A #Ford
1 B #BMW
2 C #Fiat
3 D #Dodge
```

The question is maybe having Ford in second place and BMW at the first would lead to more conversions.

The first thing I am trying to do is to generate categories for each unique group, there are about 10 different brands and 100 different ways the way they are set up.

For example:

Group1 could be:

```
0 A #Ford
1 B #BMW
2 C #Fiat
3 D #Dodge
```

Group2 could be:

```
0 B #BMW
1 A #Ford
2 C #Fiat
3 D #Dodge
```

Then my DataFrame would look like this:

```
Slug    Group   Sessions    Transactions   Ecommerce    CTR     All
a       1       70          1              1            10      10
b       2       60          2              3            15      11
c       1       60          2              3            15      11
d       3       60          2              3            15      11
e       2       60          2              3            15      11
```

`Groups` are categorized by the `position` and the `brand` column. 
`Slug` could be understood as a country. For example in Country a, having a layout of group 1 70 sessions are achieved, in country b having a layout of group 2 60 sessions are achieved and so on.

And so on, then I could compare the group performance measure in `sessions`, `transactions` and other columns values which I have in my DataFrame.

The parameters like `transactions`, `session` and others are for the entire layout of brands, for example:

```
0 Ford
1 BMW
2 Fiat
3 Dodge
# this layout achieved 70 sessions and 5 conversions
```

So my question could be divided in to 3 separate parts:

**1) How could I generate groups of `position` and `brand`**

**2) Maybe some of you had bumped in to a similar tas and knows any methods of determining the best layout of `brands`**

**3) I've tried a bit of machine learning, maybe you could suggest me which model I could apply to my problem**

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: What's the `F` under brand?

Comment: @Dan, look at the brand section values as car makes, for example, `A` is Ford, `B` is BMW and `F` could be whatever. There are different lengths of the layouts, one might only have 3 brands, other might have 7 brands. So `F` stands for `Mazda` which is placed at  4th placed in the layout. I've edited my dataframe with the car names so it would be easier to read.

Comment: So the layouts can have a different number of brands in them?

Comment: Correct, the layouts range from 3 to 9 brands in it.

Comment: @Erfan, maybe you could help out here?

Comment: Do you still need help here? @JonasPalačionis

Comment: Hi @Erfan, I've manage to group the categories. Maybe you could suggest any methods regarding my 2nd and 3rd questions at the end of the post.